# What is the smallest number of integer weights required to exactly balance every integer between $1$ and $40$?

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

> What is the smallest number of integer weights required to exactly balance every integer between $1$ and $40$.

I do not really understand what this problem is asking for me to do. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think he wants a multiset of integers (positive integers?) of minimum cardinality, so that for each number $n$ in the range  $1\le n\le 40$ there is some sub-multiset that adds up to $n$.

Comment: 4 weights are required - 1, 3, 9, 27 - the answer is so famous I even remember it!

Comment: Just to say:  the idea behind using powers of $3$ is that you can put weights on both sides.   Thus, to weigh $X=2$ you put the $3$ on one side and the $1$ on the side with $X$.  In this way you can capture the base $3$ expression for $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a set of weights consisting of specific integral weights, and you have a balance. The idea is that someone could put any integral weight up to $40$ on the left hand side, and you get to use your weights on the right hand side.

Suppose your set of weights consist of one weight each of $1,2,5,10,20$. Then you could balance some integers between $1$ and $40$, but not all of them: for example, a weight of $23$ could be balanced by putting together your $20$-weight, your $1$ weight, and your $2$-weight. On the other hand, you couldn't balance $4$, because the $1$ and $2$ aren't enough, but the $5$ is too much.

If you have enough weights, of the right sizes, to balance out any amount from $1$ to $40$, then what is the minimum number of weights you have?

The question changes if you are also allowed to add your own weights to the left side of the balance. In that case, you could balance $4$ with the above set, by putting your $1$-weight on the left, and your $5$-weight on the right. You still couldn't make $39$ though, because all of your weights only add up to $38$.

A set of "powers-of-$2$" weights is sufficient, under the first interpretation, and a set of "powers-of-$3$" weights is sufficient under the second one. The fact that the weights are meant to go up to $40$ suggests the latter interpretation, because that's the largest thing you can balance using "powers-of-$3$" weights up to $3^3$

Comment: What are integral weights? I can't really follow your explanation.

Comment: "Integral" weights just means weights that are whole numbers, so no $2.5$, or $\pi$.

Comment: Ok, your example of $23$ I don't understand how it could be balanced together with a $20$-weight, $1$ weight, and $2$ weight. What does that mean?

Comment: It means, if there are $23$ grams on one side of the balance, then you can put a $20$-gram weight, plus a $2$-gram weight, plus a $1$-gram weight on the other side, and the whole thing will balance: $23=20+2+1$.

Comment: Oh ok, so the question posed is asking what numbers I can use to balance all the numbers between 1 and 40?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The question simply asks, using which set of nos you can make every no.s between 1 to 40.

Ans: 1, 3, 9 and 27.

Using this set you can make any no from 1 to 40 with different combo.

Mark the series 3^0, 3^1, 3^2, 3^3.